# Many computers, 1 set of headphones. What are the options?

Tags: audio, music

Like many other super users I have many computers both at home and in the office.  They are connected together with a KVM.  What options exist to combine the audio from many systems so I only need a single set of speakers or headphones.

I want to be able to hear sounds from all the computers at the same time.  I want to be playing music, video, or something entertaining on one computer while I am working on another.  I want to hear the beeps and sound effects on the system I am working on while music or something is playing on another.  So a simple switch really isn't want I want.

Currently I have an older mixer hooked up, but it takes up a huge amount of desk space.  I am looking for alternatives.

To sum up, I am looking for:

- a device that will accept two to four stereo 3.5mm line-level audio sources and will merge the audio and provide 1 line level output.
- I don't need individual volume controls for each input, I can control that on the computers.
- I don't want to switch between the audio sources, I want audio from many sources at once.
- I would prefer a product I can buy, instead of something I have to build.
- I want something with a small form factor.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's a [4 channel stereo passive (unpowered) mixer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000N8LAVC), USD 50 at Amazon:

[image: doohickey]

If you can deal with switching between sources, there's a $5 option, [4 input stereo passive selector](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/276864-REG/AV_Toolbox_AVT_5041SP_AVT_5041SP_Stereo_Audio_Passive.html#specifications):

[image: thingy]

---

There's also the daisy-chain option.  Since you'll need a bunch of 3.5mm-3.5mm stereo cables anyway, you could run them from one computer to the other and just plug your headphones into the last one.

[image: GhettoMixer]

This assumes you have a stereo line-in on your computers.

Comment: Disclaimer: I don't have experience w/ either, this is just a search-paste-&-run.

Comment: +1 for diagram... +1 for search-paste-&-run... :-)

Comment: The third option you added is less then ideal.  I don't want rebooting a one computer to result in the loosing the sound from the others.  That Rolls mixer looks like it may be exactly what I want.  I'll have to buy one and try it out.

Comment: I forgot to list the actual product names: Rolls MX41b and AV Toolbox AVT-5041SP.

Comment: Zoredache - 3+ years later, how'd that mixer work out for you?